# IF-nesting in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, nested

heyall, just going through some textbook examples for my introductory c++ course and I would really appreciate it if somebody could clarify why the following code produces an output of 51 (I would expect it to not produce any output whatsoever), many thanks!:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  constexpr int a{9};
  constexpr int b{1};
  constexpr int c{5};

  if (a < b < c)
    if (c > b > a)
      if (a > c) cout << 91;
      else cout << 19;
    else
      if (b < c) cout << 51;
      else cout << 15;
  else 
    if (b < a < c)
      if (a < c) cout << 95;
      else cout << 59;
    else
      if (b < c) cout << 57;
      else cout << 75;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow! What book is giving you this example?

Comment: This is a horrible example to show to a beginner, unless the pitfall `a<b<c` is immediately explained before the example. (And even then, arguably bad). Why do you expect no output at all, though. Every if/else branch has an output statement, so one would expect one of those to be executed. Did you expect a syntax error, perhaps?

Comment: @john ahh it's not really a textbook, just some stuff the professor put together tryna devise a new method of teaching students c++.. not very effective it would seem...

Comment: @chi yea I agree, I thought because of the branching/nesting nature of if-statements, neither of the two main statements are satisfied here (the all-encompassing if and the all-encompassing else).. so surely, regardless of the sub-conditions, the a, b, and c values don't seem to satisfy the two main if-else branches... wait, so an `else if` statement is totally different from an `if` nested within an `else`? groundwork stuff..

Comment: @chi oh well I guess it makes sense that some output would have to be produced, but, not knowing about the `a<b<c` pitfall I would have said 57..

Comment: `else if` is exactly an `if` nested within an `else` as you say. You could equivalently write `if (...) {...} else { if (...) {..} else {...} }`, but `if ... else if ... else ...` is rater common.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you expect this expression:

```
if (a < b < c)
```

to be `true` if `a`, `b`, and `c` are in increasing order. But what actually happens is the expression becomes:

```
if ((a < b) < c)
```

which is either:

```
if (0 < c)
// or
if (1 < c)
```

Either way, that's probably not what you want. In fact, there's no good reason to ever write the above expression.

If you want to check whether the variables are increasing, you need to write something like:

```
if (a < b && b < c)
```

Comment: oh woooooow that changes everything! how aren't we able to translate our intuitive understanding of transitive logic into programming languages.. that seems really weird. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In c++, comparisons like 'X<=Y<=Z' do not have their mathematical meaning without parentheses. So, in

```
if (a < b < c)
```

we are getting

```
a < b => 9 < 1 => 0
```

'0' means the condition is false, which with 'c' is returning

```
0 < 5 => 1
```

"1" being returned means that the if condition is True.

Similarly, you can check for the nested if-else loops.

Comment: dammit! c-languages suuck! is this a thing in other programming languages as well?

Comment: Talking about Java, this code won't even work in Java because a<b will return boolean in java which can't be compared with int c.

Comment: oh shii hahah, maybe it's better that way